# Firestore REST API add Timestamp

Tags: rest, api, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add Data to Cloud Firestore via the REST API (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firestore/firestore/v1beta1/firestore.projects.databases.documents.createDocument)

I am able to create a new Document with e.g. an Integer Value, so the connection and the syntax seems to be ok.

In the next step I want to add the **server side timestamp** to the document. Because I  make the POST-Request from an ESP32 and the time is not available. The Request-Body looks like:

```
{  
   "fields":{  
      "myTime":{  
         "timestampValue":"SERVER_TIME_STAMP"
      }
   }
}
```

What do I have to write for SERVER_TIME_STAMP? For other languages there seems to be an Constant like *firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP* that the server will replace with its current time. But the API does not accept values like thees.

The Error-msg is

```
"code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid value at 'document.fields[0].value.timestamp_value' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Timestamp), Field 'timestampValue', Illegal timestamp format; timestamps must end with 'Z' or have a valid timezone offset.",
```

Comment: did you find out ? Do you have an example ?

Comment: This brief question was gold to me, leading to the right track about `commit` API.

Answer (score 5):

For REST API, you should use `DocumentTransform` -> `FieldTransform` -> `setToServerValue` -> set `ServerValue` as `REQUEST_TIME`.

Seems like `DocumentTransform` is only available for use on `write` and `commit` API and not `createDocument` or `patch`. You can use `commit` API as a substitute of `patch`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/Write#ServerValue