# Set server value now as timestamp

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to write the now timestamp using the rest api of firestore. The sending application doesn't keep the time so its up to the server to store the value.

```
{
    "fields": {
        "Type": {
            "stringValue": "temperature"
            },
            "Timestamp": {
                "timestampValue": "2019-02-18T23:00:00Z"
            },
            "Value": {
                "integerValue": "17"
            }
    }
}
```

The values get stored properly but I want to be able to change the static 2019-02-18T23:00:00Z to the now value.

How can this be done?

Comment: You need to use a [FieldTransform](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1#fieldtransform) for that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943408/firestore-rest-api-add-timestamp and https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/Write

Answer (score 1):

To write the server-side timestamp in a field, you need to use a [`FieldTransform`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1#fieldtransform) for that. See [Firestore REST API add Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943408/firestore-rest-api-add-timestamp) and https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/Write

Comment: Would it be possible to provide an example Json?

Comment: Nope. I was looking for that and didn't find any. I was trying in the API explorer, but keep getting sidetracked. https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firestore/firestore/v1/firestore.projects.databases.documents.patch

Comment: I feel the documentation would be way more useful with examples.

Comment: Agreed. But failing those, the best I have found is the API explorer and answer I linked. When/if I find the correct incantation, I'll add a sample JSON.