# Cloud Firestore REST API - Add server timestamp

Tags: firebase, arduino, google-cloud-firestore, esp8266

I'm using an Arduino with an ESP8266-01 module to upload a value to a Cloud Firestore database using the createDocument API with the following payload:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "distance": {
            "integerValue": "555"
        }
    }
}
```

I do a POST-request to a route like this:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/<MY_PROJECT>/databases/(default)/documents/<SOME_COLLECTION>?key=MY_VERY_SECRET_KEY
```

That all works, but I would like to add the server timestamp as well. I've found a few answers here on stackoverflow, but I have not been able to make any of them work.

How can I add the server timestamp to the created document? What I want is for the following to be created:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "distance": {
            "integerValue": "555"
        },
        "timestamp" : {
            "DATETIME": SERVER_TIMESTAMP
        }
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I remember doing this with a `FieldTransform`, but don't have a sample ready. Maybe you (or someone else) can figure it out from https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/Write#FieldTransform and the API explorer https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firestore/firestore/v1/. Also see my previous (incomplete) answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55338493/set-server-value-now-as-timestamp/55340170#55340170, which also includes a link to this gist: https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/6c8f67164f18b7b49135231f1cc0cf29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I ended up doing in the end was the following:

A POST request to a route like this:

`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/<MY_PROJECT>/databases/(default)/documents:commit?&key=<MY_VERY_SECRET_KEY>`

With the following payload:

```
{
    "writes": [
        {
            "update": {
                "name": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/databases/(default)/documents/<COLLECTION_ID>/<DOCUMENT_ID>",
                "fields": {
                    "distance": {
                        "integerValue": "555"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "transform": {
                "document": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/databases/(default)/documents/<COLLECTION_ID>/<DOCUMENT_ID>",
                "fieldTransforms": [
                    {
                        "fieldPath": "servertime",
                        "setToServerValue": "REQUEST_TIME"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Where I generate a new DOCUMENT_ID (e.g. a GUID) instead of having cloud firestore generate one for me.

Comment: Where would one find 'my very secret key' in firestore?

Comment: I'll refer you to this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api
It is the token mentioned there.